# Doom (1993) with surround sound?

Tags: doom

Anyone know of a way to play the original Doom with surround sound? Specifically I'm hoping to use my 5.1 system, but 7.1 may work too.

Comment: I know [Brutal Doom](http://www.moddb.com/mods/brutal-doom) has surround sound - or at least emulated.  Using headphones, you can easily tell which direction enemies are.  You should be able to use it the original doom as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation surround sound works with GZDoom, both FModEx and OpenAL.